# pregmatch for url validation

Tags: php, regex

I have a out using parse_url form the following:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.wine-searcher.com/merchant/26127';

echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

output is `/merchant/26127`.

I have to match a pattern with preg_match. I have a loop and I want to match all the urls which are in the form '/merchant/*number*'.

The url in the example should match.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.wine-searcher.com/merchant/26127';

$queryStr = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
var_dump(preg_match('|/merchant/\d+$|', $queryStr) == 1);
```

Should do it

Comment: You probably should add a beginning of string: `^` anchor as well. Otherwise this will erroneously match: `http://www.wine-searcher.com/other/path/merchant/26127` Otherwise +1.